Proving that $\kappa'(G) - 1 \leq \kappa'(G - v)$.
I am studying graph connectivity and need to prove the following inequality involving vertex connectivity:
$\kappa'(G) - 1 \leq \kappa'(G - v)$
I need to show that removing a vertex   from a graph  can increase the vertex connectivity by at most 1. In other words, I want to demonstrate that the vertex connectivity of the remaining graph $G - v$ is at least $\kappa'(G) - 1$
I believe that the inequality is true based on the tests I did, but I am having problems with the proof. Any guidance or detailed steps to prove this inequality would be greatly appreciated.

Let $S$ be a vertex cut of size $\kappa(G-v)$ in the graph $G-v$, which means that $G-v-S$ is disconnected. Then, we can say that $S\cup\{v\}$ is a vertex cut in the graph $G$, thus $\kappa(G)\leq|S\cup\{v\}|=\kappa(G-v)+1$.
